# VBA in Word: If then to toggle bookmarks hidden/unhidden

Tags: vba

This VBA code seems like it should work to toggle hidden = True/ False on bookmarks in Word, but it doesn't.

```
Private Sub Instructions_Click()

If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("InstText").Range.Font.Hidden = True Then

Bookmarks("InstText").Range.Font.Hidden = False

Else

Bookmarks("InstText").Range.Font.Hidden = True

End If

End Sub
```

This next one works (if you click the `Instructions` button, the appropriate bookmarked text is unhidden)

```
Private Sub Instructions_Click()

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("InstText").Range.Font.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

Another idea I saw is this one:

```
Private Sub Instructions_Click()

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("InstText").Range.Font.Hidden = Not  ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("InstText").Range.Font.Hidden
```

Which is supposed to flip it to whatever it's not, basically. But that doesn't work for me.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the first one? I'm guessing that the hidden property can't be used as a condition for some reason, but -- why not? Or is it something else? What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to Normal > NewMacros:

```
Sub Toggle_Bookmarks()
    ActiveWindow.View.ShowBookmarks = Not ActiveWindow.View.ShowBookmarks
End Sub
```

1. Right-click Microsoft Word Ribbon
2. Customize Quick Access Toolbar
3. Above left list, choose command from macros
4. Select Normal.Newmacros.Toggle_Bookmarks
5. Click Add
6. Click OK

Now you have a toggle in the quick Access toolbar to click on to toggle bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the question, but it is some insight for people using his question for their own problem.

For some reason, the if statement doesn't compute .Range.Font.Hidden = False. It does, however, compute if you use .Range.Font.Hidden = True.

So you've got to use Else: to work around it. Kind of a double negative situation.

```
'SF1
```

If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SF1").Range.Font.Hidden = True Then

Else: ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SF1X").Range.Font.Hidden = False

End If``

Comment: format the code block please

Answer (score 0):

In my own Word add-in, I display a list of all the bookmarks found. The user clicks on the bookmark (or multiple bookmarks) and click the Toggle button to switch the visibility.

My routine loops through all the selected bookmarks and uses these two lines of code:

```
.Bookmarks(intHideShowBookmark).Select
.Bookmarks(intHideShowBookmark).Range.Font.Hidden = Not _ .Bookmarks(intHideShowBookmark).Range.Font.Hidden
```

Which is using the third option you mentioned. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but to directly answer your question, I have essentially the same code in my doc and it works (mine just looks for the visibility of another bookmark). However, an alternative option is to use the button value for something like that. Similar to your third code block.

I am assuming that nothing else unhides the instructions bookmark so something like this should since the hidden value should theoretically always be the inverse of the button value:

```
Private Sub Instructions_Click()

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("InstText").Range.Font.Hidden = Instructions.Value

End Sub
```

I don't have enough rep to comment on @gtrplyr6283's reply but using Not is another way to use the double negative workaround so you can use if's normally.